# The following delegate functions for iOS

Tags: ios

In the base.h  It implement a delegate function

```
id<MADayViewDataSource> _dataSource;

@protocol MADayViewDataSource <NSObject>

- (NSArray *)dayView:(MADayView *)dayView eventsForDate:(NSDate *)date;
@end
```

In the base.m

```
- (void)setDataSource:(id <MADayViewDataSource>)dataSource {
    _dataSource = dataSource;
    [self reloadData];
}

- (id <MADayViewDataSource>)dataSource {
    return _dataSource;
}

- (void)reloadData {
    NSArray *events = [self.dataSource dayView:self eventsForDate:self.day];
}
```

In top Viewcontroller.h  It implement the MADayViewDatasource delegate from base.h

```
      :UIViewController<MADayViewDataSource> { }
```

In base.m, It implement that delegate function

```
- (NSArray *)dayView:(MADayView *)dayView eventsForDate:(NSDate *)startDate {
```

So, my understanding of the code is
when the function inside the base.m is called

```
[self.datasource dayView:self eventsForDate:self.day];
```

The `self.datasource` would call `-(void)setDataSource <MADayViewDataSource>)dataSource {}` which return the _datasource....etc  anyway, I am lost..

***My question what's sequence of fucntion being called? How does the datasource from base relate to the array returning from the delegate function from the top viewcontroller?***

Comment: What class do the 3 method implementations in base.m exist in?  And what is the name of the class that inherits from UIViewController and implements your protocol?  The names of the files don't tell anything specifically, only suggest what should be going on.  Its unclear if you are implementing the protocol method in the correct place.

Comment: @Matt, No inheritance from UIViewController,   Base.m is a UIView.

Comment: :UIViewController<MADayViewDataSource> { } is a partial class declaration of a class that inherits from UIViewController and implements the MADayViewDataSource protocol.  The whole thing would look like... (At sign)interface AClassName : UIViewController<MADayViewDataSource> {} (At sign)end